# Checking if $_POST variable is set using mysql variable

Tags: php, mysql, forms, checkbox

I have a php file that is receiving some checkbox values from a form. Both the checkbox name and value are set up to match an Item_Name field in a mysql table. My current attempt is below:

```
while($row = $items->fetch_assoc()){
        if( isset($_POST[$row['Item_Name']])) {
            \\ Code to perform if true, mostly echoes
        }
    }

//Checkbox setup: 

echo  "<input type='checkbox' name=" . $row['Item_Name'] .  "value=" . $row['Item_Name'] .  ">"
```

$items is the data returned by my query of the mysql table. Currently none of the echoes inside the if are triggering so I think something is wrong with my if statement, but I'm to new to php to know what is wrong exactly.

Comment: There's not enough code to know why. Let's say `$row['Item_Name']` is `Bags`. Now PHP is looking for `$_POST['bags']`. Beyond that, it's up to you to debug it. Maybe try `var_dump($_POST);`?

Comment: You need a `foreach` for this and making sure that the inputs have the `[]` multiple array brackets.

Comment: @Machavity my bad I did a var dump of $_POST and it returned this ```array(2) { ["Applevalue=Apple"]=> string(2) "on" ["Milkvalue=Milk"]=> string(2) "on" }```

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner would the foreach be replacing the while loop here. I'm just slightly confused on what it would look like

Comment: I'm guessing the values in `$row['Item_Name']` are actually `Apple` and `Milk` etc. so the problem would appear to be in the generation of the `name` attributes of your checkboxes.

Comment: @Nick just added the checkbox setup in for reference

Comment: You should have gotten a parse error with what you added for the checkbox.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner actually it does come out as semi-legitimate HTML, you get `<input type='checkbox' name=Milkvalue=Milk>` which I guess most browsers parse as `<input type='checkbox' name="Milkvalue=Milk">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your checkbox setup; you are missing quotes around the `name` and `value` attributes. Try this instead:

```
echo  "<input type='checkbox' name=\"" . $row['Item_Name'] .  "\" value=\"" . $row['Item_Name'] .  "\">";
```